# determine the period of missing payments

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having a problem finding the missing payment ( passed 90 days from their last paid contribution) and the period catch-up(payment which covers more than a month ) payment had covered in our DB. the tables I have as follow
contributions table with (id, employees_id, starts_on, ends_on,payment_id ) 
the starts_on and ends_on defined the period they are contributing for (from_to)
the payments table has  (id,amount_pennies and paid_at "null if they didn't pay").
I wrote this query to get the starts_on and ends_on for each pay per company and I ranked the last paid_at and the largest payment (value) assuming it the catch-up payment.

```
  SELECT
company_id
, o.starts_on
, date_part('day', o.ends_on :: TIMESTAMP - o.starts_on :: TIMESTAMP) start_to_end
, o.ends_on
, date_part('day', o.paid_at :: TIMESTAMP - o.ends_on :: TIMESTAMP)   ends_to_paid
, o.paid_at
, date_part('day', current_date :: TIMESTAMP - o.paid_at)             paid_to_now
, rank_1
, rank_2
, amount
FROM
(
  SELECT
    p.id
    , company_id
    , min(c.starts_on)                 starts_on
    , max(c.ends_on)                   ends_on
    , max(date(paid_at))               paid_at
    , amount_pennies / 100.00          amount
    , row_number()
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY company_id
        ORDER BY max(c.ends_on) DESC ) rank_1
    , rank()
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY company_id
        ORDER BY amount_pennies DESC ) rank_2
  FROM payments p
    JOIN contributions c
      ON p.id = c.payment_id
  WHERE company_id NOT IN (
    SELECT company_id
    FROM flags
    WHERE type IN (0, 2))
  GROUP BY company_id, p.id
  ORDER BY company_id, rank_1 ASC) o
```

what I really need is if a company ends_on for the last paid payment in the last three months then find the starts_on and ends_on for their last catch-up payment, if they don't have a payment in the last there month then find the starts_on and ends_on for their last paid payment. I am sorry if that not clear enough or too long

Comment: Got lost in the text. Try adding a sample data (no need to be real, just close to your explanation) and from the sample data what would be the desired result. That will be way clearer for anyone trying to understand your problem. See here [Tips to a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557)

Comment: thank you, Jorge, I am sorry my question wasn't clear enough, i'll to try to edit it as I wasn't able to add sample data

Answer (score 0):

the missing period is the period between last payment and now for a paid bill

```
      with payment as (select
               company_id
               , min(start_on)                                                             starts_o
               , date_part('day', max(end_on) :: timestamp - min(start_on) :: TIMestamp)   start_to_end
               , max(end_on)                                                               ends_o
               , date_part('day', max(paied_att) :: timestamp - max(end_on) :: TIMestamp)  ends_to_paid
               , max(paied_att)                                                            paid_at
               , date_part('day', current_date :: timestamp - max(paied_att) :: timestamp) paid_now
               , sum(EE_per_payment)                                                       contribution_count
               , sum(amount)                                                               amount


             from


               (
                 select
                   p.id
                   , company_id
                   , count(distinct employee_id) EE_per_payment
                   , min(c.starts_on)            start_on
                   , max(c.ends_on)              end_on
                   , date(p.paid_at)             paied_att
                   , (amount_pennies) / 100.00   amount
                   , sum(employee_amount_pennies + company_amount_pennies + voluntary_amount_pennies) /
                     100.00                      contribution
                 from payments p left join contributions c
                     on p.id = c.payment_id
                 where c.state = 'invested' and p.state = 'paid_out'
                 group by p.id, p.company_id
                 order by company_id asc) o
             group by company_id) select
                                    p.*
                                    , round((p.amount / (p.start_to_end / 30)) :: numeric, 2) avr_per_month
                                    , round(((p.amount / (p.start_to_end / 30)) * (paid_now / 30)) :: numeric,
                                            2)                                                outstanding

                                  from payment p

                                  where paid_now >= 90 and amount > 0;
```